# "object required" error when using return value from function?

Tags: vba

I have a function that finds the current date in a range and returns the cell in which it's found. I'm trying to use that cell's position to calculate an offset within a subroutine. However, when I run the macro, I get `objected required` as an error. The function and the subroutine are as shown:

```
Function findCurrentDate() As Range
    Dim needle As Date
    Dim rng As Range
    needle = CLng(Date)
    Dim haystack As Range
    Dim search As Range
    Set haystack = Range("B3:B86")
    Set search = haystack.Find(needle, After:=haystack(1), _
                           LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlNext, MatchByte:=True)
End Function

Sub showFutureWeeklyHours()
    Dim wkday_row_offset As Integer
    Dim search As Range
    Set search = findCurrentDate()
    Set wkday_row_offset = search.Row
...
End Sub
```

This isn't the complete subroutine, but it's enough to reproduce the error. The list of dates are stored in cells `B3:B86`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `wkday_row_offset` is a number, not an object, so do not use Set.

```
"This method returns Nothing if no match is found. The Find method does not affect the selection or the active cell."
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839746.aspx

You will need to check that something is returned before looking for the row property. Nothing does not have a row. A row is a number, not an object.

```
Function findCurrentDate() As Range
    Dim needle As Date
    Dim rng As Range
    needle = CLng(Date)
    Dim haystack As Range
    Dim search As Range
    Set haystack = Range("B3:B86")
    Set search = haystack.Find(needle, After:=haystack(1), _
                           LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlNext, MatchByte:=True)
    Set findCurrentDate = search
End Function

Sub showFutureWeeklyHours()
    Dim wkday_row_offset As Integer
    Dim search As Range
    Set search = findCurrentDate()

    wkday_row_offset = search.row
''...
End Sub
```

Comment: If I remove the `Set` keyword from the `wkday_row_offset` line, I get the following error: `Object variable or with block variable not set` Any other ideas?

Comment: Based on your update, how would I check if something is returned? Since I tested this function several minutes ago, it *does* return a value because the search string `6/1/2012` does exist in the worksheet. Therefore, shouldn't the function (in this case) be returning a value?

Comment: You need to set the function to search, `set findCurrentDate = search`. You said this is a fragment and asked about one error.

Comment: Could you post a code snippet detailing what you're talking about? Changing this line: `Set search = findCurrentDate()` to your suggestion of: `set findCurrentDate = search` throws an `Invalid use of property error` I thought maybe you accidentally reversed it, so I tried this: `Set search = findCurrentDate` but that returns the same `Object variable or with block variable not set` error. Yes, this is a fragment, but it was enough to reproduce the first error, which is what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: The above is your code with the suggested changes and tested as working. You should test that search is not nothing as per my link before getting the row.

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't realise that the `set findCurrentDate = search` code snippet was part of the function and not the subroutine. The code appears to be working now. Thank you for the help.